# A biconnected graph $G$ where the degree of all vertices is at least 3 must have an edge whose removal retains the biconnectivity of $G$

Tags: graph-theory

We have a biconnected graph $G$ wherein the degree of each vertex is at least 3. Then G contains at least one edge, $e$, whose removal means the graph $G-e$ is still biconnected.

I know that for a graph to be biconnected, for any two vertices in $G$, there must exist at least one cycle containing these two vertices.

I'm not sure how to proceed however, my intuition involved somehow showing that we can always find 2 vertices in such a graph as detailed above that the two vertices are contained within at least two cycles, as we could then identify these two vertices and delete an edge emanating from them. But I am not sure.

Comment: Use the ear decomposition.